# Object this keyword in properties

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 700;
const h = canvas.height;
const w = canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const snake = {
  width: w / 12,
  height: h / 12,
  blocks: [[40, 30, this.width, this.height]],
  renderSnake() {
    this.blocks.forEach((b) => {
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(...b);
      console.log(this.blocks);
    });
    console.log(this.blocks);
  },
};
```

In my code the problem is in the blocks property in the snake object. this.width and this.height was undefined and I added some console.log and realised that the this keyword in the blocks array property was pointing to the Window object, how do i make it point at the snake object or make this work without hardcoding the width and height.

Comment: If you want `blocks` to be dynamic it should be a function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#as_an_object_method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `blocks` a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```
get blocks(){
    return [[40, 30, this.width, this.height]];
}
```